# Monotouch, Instruments and leaks

Tags: xamarin.ios, instruments

I have test-run my app with Instruments and it finds a couple of leaks. They are a lot of 16 byte leaks. All in all not a lot of memory leaked, but still I'm wondering. In the MT forums over at Novell I read a statement that Instruments is not very good in understanding MT's garbage collector ([http://forums.monotouch.net/yaf_postst751.aspx)](http://forums.monotouch.net/yaf_postst751.aspx). The post is from March 2010 - is it still true?

Which templates of Instruments are reliable for use with MT applications?

Comment: @Tim Cooper: Just out of curiosity: why are you removing my name from the question? Not that it hurts but I don't see a reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of Instruments showing the leaks? I noticed in one of my apps there are 2 small leaks at the beginning, but nothing after that. Instruments has worked fine for me - you can test it by adding a button that forces garbage collection at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I'm on MT 5 and there are no more such issues. So, resolved by Xamarin.